# Find all video files in directory with FLAC audio codec

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, mediainfo

Is it possible to search a directory and output a text file listing every video file that has FLAC audio?

My television doesn't support FLAC so when I run into one I have been converting them with a FFMPEG script but it would be nice to be able to find them all in advance instead of waiting until I hit the problem while trying to play the files. I'm hoping there is a way that doesn't involve just opening every file in Mediainfo and checking manually.

Maybe there is a way to just output all of the Mediainfo information for a directory and then I can just find all FLAC occurrences in a csv sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open all files in MediaInfo then export to CSV then open the CSV in a spreadsheet processor, or for a smaller output you can customize the output with the command line version of MediaInfo (see the download section on the MediaInfo website and download the CLI version) and a template file template.txt containing:

```
General;%CompleteName%,
Audio;%Format%
Audio_Middle;,
File_End;\n
```

and this command line:

```
mediainfo --Output=file://template.txt --ParseSpeed=0 YourDir > List.txt
```

`List.txt` will contain a CSV file with complete file name in first column, then audio format per track (2nd column has 1st audio format, 3rd column has 2nd audio format...)

`--Output=file://template.txt` selects the template file.
`--ParseSpeed=0` reduces the parsing speed (no need of the extra info from a longer parsing).
`YourDir` is to be replaced by the directory name you want to scan.
`> List.txt` sends the output to a file.

Comment: Thank you. That command line argument was exactly what I needed and I appreciate you explaining the parameters!